# Bandwith/requests monitor on IIS 7/win server 2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, network-monitoring

Recently i noticed that my VPS bandwith jumped from 20-30 GB per month to 150-400 GB per month in the last few months and i want to know which sites on the server are generating the most bandwith and if possible to pinpoint which files are being accesed the most (static images/files and dynamic files .php/aspx )

Any tips on how to setup such monitoring or what software to use would be usefull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix your units. `gb` isn't a unit that's used to measure bandwidth or usage and `Gb` / `GB` are very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this information is in your IIS logs. You can either parse them yourself in some way, perhaps with the help of Excel, or, you can use a tool that does it for you.

A quick google for "IIS 7 log analyser" will give you plenty of options.

Comment: +1 As an aside I would suggest checking out Smarter Tools, specifically their Stats product.  I think you can get the free version for a single site.  By far the easiest and most detailed reports I have seen in a while.